# Events 4720 and 4732 not being created in the Event Viewer (Server 2008)

Tags: windows-server-2008, event-viewer

These events are related to user creation and adding user to the administrator group in Windows Server 2008

They are not being created when I create a user or when I add the user to a group, in this case, administrator.
Is there a way to enable them in the log?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The Audit Account Management in Local Policies was set to No Auditing.
Success and Failure should've been checked.